# Why am I getting this error in python ? httplib.BadStatusLine

Tags: python, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting this error in python ? (httplib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767934/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-python-httplib)

i have some problem with coding in python, i want to create web service with abyssws python in local python service, but i cannot receive response..whereas i get response when i request from browser..

my code like this :

```
import httplib
IP = "local ip"
v_params = ""
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(IP,8021)
conn.request("GET", v_params)
response = conn.getresponse() 
data_response = response.read()
```

and getting error ilke this

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C:\Python24\lib\httplib.py", line 866, in getresponse
   response.begin()
File "C:\Python24\lib\httplib.py", line 336, in begin
 version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Python24\lib\httplib.py", line 300, in _read_status
 raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine
```

any suggestion??please help me?

Comment: Try not to re-invent the wheel. Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The server you connected to did not send a proper HTTP response line. Such a response should consist of a number followed by a human-readable textual description, like:

```
200 Ok
```

or

```
404 Not Found
```

You need to verify what the server on port 8021 sends. Try using `telnet IP 8021` from the terminal, then entering something like `GET / HTTP/1.1` plus two newlines to see what is returned by the server.

I note that your `v_params` string is empty; it may be your server expects at least the empty path (`/`). However, not sending a properly formatted error code in that case is still a violation of the HTTP standard.