# trying to set path for selenium / phantomjs on win7

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to work through http://blog.likewise.org/2013/04/webdriver-testing-with-python-and-ghostdriver/. My development environment is a usb drive on win7. I have phantomjs.exe on:

```
f:/phantomjs.exe
```

Using the python REPL I have done the following based on the article:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="F:\phantomjs.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 66, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Following [Can't run PhantomJS in python via Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435220/cant-run-phantomjs-in-python-via-selenium?rq=1), I uninstalled selenium from my virtualenv and ran:

```
pip install selenium==2.37
```

So far this has been working for me , although the above articles indicates there are some problems at least.

Comment: this issue seems to be fixed in selenium 2.42.1

Comment: why not put it in as an answer?