# "Connection aborted" and "Cannot connect to proxy"

Tags: python, python-requests

When the code bellow is running

```
import requests
monitor_r = requests.get(monitor_url, proxies=proxies, timeout=60*4)
```

I get these exceptions:

```
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
# and 
('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(32, 'Broken pipe')))
```

What are these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: lol, that probably means proxy is not good.
Check out these exceptions - that should help you understand what is what :-)
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions

Comment: are you trying to connect to a `https` url?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2364) link suggests that it is caused at the `httplib` level.

1. It may be caused by trying to connect to a `https` url using `http` try using `https://` and see if it works...
2. Double check your url doesn't contain any [dodgy characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017158/4013571)
3. Check your proxy is accepting headers

Comment: I had this problem and 1. seems to have applied to my case.