# Locust : ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",)),)

Tags: python, python-2.7, load-testing, locust

I am performing `Load-tests` for some `Rest APIs` using `Locust`. Everything is working fine except for the error which has confused me:

```
ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",)),)
```

I have read other questions regarding this problem and came across the fact that:

> This error arises when python is unable to understand the server
>   response.

What I want to know is:

**1)** If this issue is with server what could be remedy?

**2)** Is this issue is caused by malfunction code of the test?

I want to know this error is due to `test` written in `Locust` or the server which is malfunctioning. Please let me know if I am not clear in asking question.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Please let me know if you have figured it out.

Comment: I have the same issue too, and I'm investigating it

Comment: This is most likely a malfunctioning server. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029420/1591921

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locust.io Load Testing getting "Connection aborted BadStatusLine" Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600508/locust-io-load-testing-getting-connection-aborted-badstatusline-errors)