# When initially creating a chromedriver in python, http.client.BadStatusLine: '' is thrown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When creating a new chromedriver instance (in python): `webdriver.Chrome("./venv/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver")`, I get an error `http.client.BadStatusLine: ''`. I am not navigating to a site, or using a server, just creating a new chromedriver. I am in a VirtualEnv that has the most recent version of Selenium (3.0.1) and chromedriver (2.24.1). This was working fine a few days ago, and I didn't change any code. I'm not really sure where to begin solving the code. My first step was to run `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` to make sure all packages were up to date. My only idea now is that selenium is no handling the default start page, with url as `data;,`, because there is no response. However, as that is the default behavior, I would be surprised if selenium could not handle its' own default behavior. Any help would be much appreciated!

When the code is run (via python from the bash terminal), a new chromedriver instance is successfully created, but the error `http.client.BadStatusLine: ''` gets thrown, and the python terminal loses the connection to the chromedriver.

Full code:

```
import pythonscripts
# Creates a new webdriver
driver = pythonscripts.md()
# Never gets here, attempts to use driver get NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

Pythonscripts md method:

```
def md():
    return webdriver.Chrome("./venv/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver")
```

Full error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/cad_tests/pythonscripts.py", line 65, in md
    return webdriver.Chrome("./venv/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver")
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Users/brydenr/server_scripts/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 439, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Tried doing

```
try:
    webdriver.Chrome("./venv/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver")
except Exception:
    webdriver.Chrome("./venv/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver")
```

The result is two of the same traceback as before, and two chromedriver instances. It seems like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681605/python-webdriver-raises-http-client-badstatusline-error) points to an error in `urllib`, but it is for a slightly different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me after I updated chrome to the latest version.
I just updated chromedriver to 2.25 and it works again.

Comment: This fixes it! As an added note, the current version of `pip` does not have chromedriver 2.25 yet.