# Error: httplib.py in_read_status raise BadStatusLine(line) BadStatusLine on ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, http, ubuntu, web-scraping

I am scraping a site using selenium in python, I get the desired results when I run the same script on windows, but in ubuntu 16.04 when I run the same script it throws error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 402, in_read_status
  raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

can anyone give me an idea why is this error raised?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 402, in_read_status raise BadStatusLine(line) BadStatusLine
```

...implies that the **BadStatusLine** was raised as the server responded with a HTTP status code that we don’t understand.

---

### httplib.BadStatusLine

[exception httplib.BadStatusLine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.BadStatusLine) is defined in [Python2.x - httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) / [Python3.x - http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) module and is subclass of [HTTPException](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPException) which is raised if a server responds with a HTTP status code that we don’t understand.

---

### Reasons and Solutions

There can be many reason behind seeing the **httplib.BadStatusLine** exception. As per [Why am I getting this error in python ? (httplib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767934/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-python-httplib) some of the pottential reasons and solutions are:

- You may be trying to use `http://` instead of `https://`
- The *URL* string may be containing a trailing newline character. So make sure that your *URL* are stripped of any leading or trailing special characters.
- The *Web Server* may be down and *Not Responding*.
- The *Server* may be closing the *connection* before sending a valid response.
- Presence of `Content-Length` within the **`http header`** can also create this exception.
- If the time interval between two requests are more than he configured time of `Keep-Alive timeout=n`.
- An easy solution would be to establish a new connection through **`conn.connect()`** before sending each request.

Comment: almost all of these "Reasons" wouldn't result in a `BadStatusLine` exception.